# How to display values from JSF Bean in facets?

Tags: jsf, facet

I have created a little popup dialog with header, content and footer.

Now I want to get some information from the database using my JSF bean to display who was the last person that edited this account.

This is what I did:

```html
<f:facet name="footer">
  <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="display:block; ">
    <h:outputText class="customerVieFooter" value="Created at "/>
    <h:outputText class="customerVieFooter" value="#{customerController.customer.createdAt}">
      <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>
  </h:panelGroup>
</f:facet>
```

When I run this I am just getting the first `outputText` because the second does not seem to get the value.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does it happen only with the footer facet? Do you get any error?

Comment: @XtremeBiker it does happen in the Header too. No I dont get an Error

Comment: Can you show your entire dialog code? And the managed bean too.

Comment: i have the same issue , did you found a solution?

Comment: @Selma I had to outsource everything and build a div inside the main content. I did not manage to display the value directly inside the footer